# anyway to optimize this multiple insert query?

Tags: c#, optimization

So I have 3 tables given on the codes below 
I don't know if there's any way to optimize this because I think it's not the proper way to insert data especially if you're dealing with normalization.

```
string mySqlCon = "Server = localhost; port = 3306; database = rmsdb; Uid = root; pwd=''"; //connection string

private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(mySqlCon);
    MySqlCommand cmd;

    try
    {
        if (firstnametb.Text.Length > 0 && lastnametb.Text.Length > 0 && gendercb.Text.Length > 0 && addresstb.Text.Length > 0 && birthdatetb.Text.Length > 0 && gradelevelcb.Text.Length > 0 && sectioncb.Text.Length > 0 && positioncb.Text.Length > 0 && empstatuscb.Text.Length > 0 && fiutb.Text.Length > 0 && oadtb.Text.Length > 0 && prctb.Text.Length > 0 && gsistb.Text.Length > 0 && csetb.Text.Length > 0 && contacttb.Text.Length > 0 && usernametb.Text.Length > 0 && passwordtb.Text.Length > 0 && questioncb.Text.Length > 0 && answertb.Text.Length > 0)
        {

            string CmdString = "INSERT INTO TeachersINFO('teachersid',firstname,lastname,gender,address,birthdate,position,empstatus,contactnumber,gradelevel,section,status) values (@teachersid,@firstname,@lastname,@gender,@address,@birthdate,@position,@empstatus,@contactnumber,@gradelevel,@section,@status);" +Environment.NewLine+
                               "INSERT INTO teacherslogin(teachersid,username,password,secretquestion,answer,status) values (@teachersid2,@username,@password,@secretquestion,@answer,@status2);" +Environment.NewLine+
                               "INSERT INTO teachersref(teachersid,FIU,oad,PrcNo,GSISBPNo,UMIDNo,TinNo,PhilHealthNo,CivilServiceE) values (@teachersid3,@FIU,@oad,@PrcNo,@GSISBPNo,@UMIDNo,@TinNo,@PhilHealthNo)";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teachersid", teacheridtb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstnametb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastnametb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gendercb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addresstb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", birthdatetb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", positioncb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empstatus", empstatuscb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnumber", contacttb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gradelevel", gradelevelcb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", sectioncb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", 1);
            //secondtable values p0ta kahit pandurugas to wala kong pake stored procedures parin tawag dito HAHAHA//
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teachersid2", teacheridtb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernametb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordtb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secretquestion", questioncb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", answertb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status2",1);
            //thirdtable values hahaha pota pandaraya so much 


            con.Open();
            int RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (RowsAffected > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Registered Successfully", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                firstnametb.Text = "";
                lastnametb.Text = "";
                gendercb.SelectedItem = null;
                lastnametb.Text = "";
                addresstb.Text = "";
                gradelevelcb.SelectedItem = null;
                sectioncb.SelectedItem = null;
                answertb.Text = "";
                usernametb.Text = "";
                passwordtb.Text = "";
                questioncb.Text = "";
                empstatuscb.Text = "";
                positioncb.Text = "";
                fiutb.Text = "";
                oadtb.Text = "";
                prctb.Text = "";
                gsistb.Text = "";
                csetb.Text = "";


                con.Close();
                //clearing textboxes fields.


            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incomplete Data", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? You have 3 tables, and insert data into them. Apart from bulk uploads (`COPY` or `MERGE` commands), `INSERT` is a standard way to get data into the db? The only thing i'd recommend is calling your columns and variables something more legible, as well as removing `hahaha` from the comments...

Comment: im sorry for the comments, btw thankyou ! i'll do a stored procedure for it

Comment: use stored proc for reuse of execution plan and most important than optimization check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql

Comment: @empoyasilo It's fine. Comments help improve the answer further. I would also advise you to look into the brykneval 's comment as well as Bozhidar Stoinev's answer. Following the information they've pointed out would help you write better queries from both optimisation and security point of view.

Comment: @empoyasilo also as a general policy, if an answer solves your question, please mark it as answer. If you find more than one answer helpful up vote them as well. This will help the community be more organised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the approach to updating the data.
However, there's a lot of room for C# code optimization as well as the program reliability.

First of all, `try/catch/finally` blocks are not meant for managing `IDisposable` resources. You can make your C# code more readable, by making use of a `using` block instead. Then trap the database call and at least log any errors. That way, your program will sustain a database server failure and continue to execute. Later, you can inspect the logs and see what the error was and figure out how to fight it in the next program release.

```
string mySqlCon = "Server = localhost; port = 3306; database = rmsdb; Uid = root; pwd=''"; //connection string

private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var succeeded = false;

    var canUpdate = firstnametb.Text.Length > 0
        && lastnametb.Text.Length > 0
        && gendercb.Text.Length > 0
        && addresstb.Text.Length > 0
        && birthdatetb.Text.Length > 0
        && gradelevelcb.Text.Length > 0
        && sectioncb.Text.Length > 0
        && positioncb.Text.Length > 0
        && empstatuscb.Text.Length > 0
        && fiutb.Text.Length > 0
        && oadtb.Text.Length > 0
        && prctb.Text.Length > 0
        && gsistb.Text.Length > 0
        && csetb.Text.Length > 0
        && contacttb.Text.Length > 0
        && usernametb.Text.Length > 0
        && passwordtb.Text.Length > 0
        && questioncb.Text.Length > 0
        && answertb.Text.Length > 0;

    if (canUpdate)
    {
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(mySqlCon))
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd = "INSERT INTO TeachersINFO('teachersid',firstname,lastname,gender,address,birthdate,position,empstatus,contactnumber,gradelevel,section,status) values (@teachersid,@firstname,@lastname,@gender,@address,@birthdate,@position,@empstatus,@contactnumber,@gradelevel,@section,@status);" + Environment.NewLine
                + "INSERT INTO teacherslogin(teachersid,username,password,secretquestion,answer,status) values (@teachersid2,@username,@password,@secretquestion,@answer,@status2);" + Environment.NewLine
                + "INSERT INTO teachersref(teachersid,FIU,oad,PrcNo,GSISBPNo,UMIDNo,TinNo,PhilHealthNo,CivilServiceE) values (@teachersid3,@FIU,@oad,@PrcNo,@GSISBPNo,@UMIDNo,@TinNo,@PhilHealthNo)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teachersid", teacheridtb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstnametb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastnametb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gendercb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addresstb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", birthdatetb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", positioncb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empstatus", empstatuscb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnumber", contacttb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gradelevel", gradelevelcb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", sectioncb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", 1);
            //secondtable values p0ta kahit pandurugas to wala kong pake stored procedures parin tawag dito HAHAHA//
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teachersid2", teacheridtb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernametb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordtb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secretquestion", questioncb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", answertb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status2", 1);
            //thirdtable values hahaha pota pandaraya so much 

            con.Open();
            try
            {
                var RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                succeeded = RowsAffected > 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the captured exception here
                // E.g. if using NUnit do:
                //      Log.Fatal(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        if (succeeded)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Registered Successfully", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            firstnametb.Text = "";
            lastnametb.Text = "";
            gendercb.SelectedItem = null;
            lastnametb.Text = "";
            addresstb.Text = "";
            gradelevelcb.SelectedItem = null;
            sectioncb.SelectedItem = null;
            answertb.Text = "";
            usernametb.Text = "";
            passwordtb.Text = "";
            questioncb.Text = "";
            empstatuscb.Text = "";
            positioncb.Text = "";
            fiutb.Text = "";
            oadtb.Text = "";
            prctb.Text = "";
            gsistb.Text = "";
            csetb.Text = "";
            //clearing textboxes fields.
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some I/O error has occured.", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incomplete Data", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: it says cannot use cmd because it's using as a variable. btw thankyou.

Comment: You must be more specific when you're describing a problem... Anyways, I guess your problem is that you haven't deleted your previous declarations. E.g. the line `MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(mySqlCon);` and `MySqlCommand cmd;`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using a stored procedure that takes in all these parameters and then does the insert.

Using a stored procedure can help optimise the code as the stored procedure has already been compiled before it is called in the C# code. That should help with optimisation.

You can also use something like EntityFramework to help you avoid writing SQL commands by yourself.

Comment: How is that vulnerable to SQL injection if the OP is already using parameters?

Comment: I stand corrected. I thought even parameters were replaced like interpolated text unless used along with a stored procedure. I'll edit my answer